# inf sup problem need help

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let  $\Bbb{M} $  be the set of decreasing smooth functions in $[0,1]$
for which $f(1)=0.$

Find $$\inf_{f \in \Bbb{M}}\sup_{x \in [0;1]} \frac{x*f(x)}{{\int_{0}^1}f(t)dt}
$$

Let now $F(x)=x*f(x)$. 
I only find out that $ F(0)=0 $  and $F(1)=0$. Only idea is to proof somehow that F is concave and use Rolle's theorem. Can you give some hints?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The only thing I found is that this infimum is at most $1/e$. This can be shown considering $f(x)=(1-x)^n$ and sending $n \to \infty$.

Comment: What operation is meant by $*$? Multiplication or convolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inf-sup is zero. Clearly, the quantity in question is non-negative. Let me show that the infimum is indeed zero..

Let $s<1$, define $f(x) = x^{-s}-1$. Then $\int_0^1 f(x) = \frac1{1-s}-1 = \frac s{s-1}$. The function $x f(x)$ has derivative $(1-s)x^{-s}-1$. Hence the product is minimal at $x_s=(1-s)^{\frac1s}$.

Then
$$
\frac{\sup_x  xf(x) }{\int f dt} = ( (1-s)^{\frac{1-s}s}-(1-s)^{\frac1s}) \cdot \frac{s-1}s
= \frac1s ((1-s)^{\frac1s}-(1-s)^{\frac1s+1})
$$
which tends to zero for $s\nearrow 1$.

If you do not like to take this function with pole at zero, you can replace it by some smooth function: Define $f_\epsilon(x) = f(x)$ on $(\epsilon,1]$,
$f_\epsilon(x)\le f(x)$ on $(0,\epsilon)$, such that $f_\epsilon$ is smooth and decreasing. For $\epsilon<x_s$, the $\sup_x xf(x)$ is unchanged, while $\int_0^1 f_\epsilon$ will converge to $\int_0^1 f$ for $\epsilon\to0$.